# How to print to a printer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-print

I am developing an app in rails and I need to know how I can print some file through thermal printer. There is anyone that can explain me how do that? It's better to print file directly from rails or js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Have you tried using the gem?

https://github.com/thegengen/cloudprint

Comment: @Max Chrétien I'm sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Mark I prefer to develop the code I needed. I'm afraid the gems may not be reliable in terms of time.